# SUMIFS, with < or > criteria

Tags: excel, excel-formula, formula

May be an easy thing for someone more knowledgable than I, but i'm learning :) I have this formula which aims to sum column N if O is "x" and G is "y" and it works fine:

```
=SUMIFS(Data_Sheet!N:N,Data_Sheet!O:O,Summary!$A$6,Data_Sheet!G:G,"INF")
```

I want to add a third criteria that only sums N if O > 0. I have tried using the same formula syntax but can't get it to work. any ideas on where i'm going wrong?

```
=SUMIFS(Data_Sheet!N:N,Data_Sheet!O:O,Summary!$A$6,Data_Sheet!G:G,"INF",Data_Sheet!O:O,<0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The criteria for `<` or `>` or `>=` or `<=` needs to be in quotes:

```
=SUMIFS(Data_Sheet!N:N,Data_Sheet!O:O,Summary!$A$6,Data_Sheet!G:G,"INF",Data_Sheet!O:O,">0")
```

Note that I changed the sign to `>` in my answer since your text said `>0` *where as your formula said `<0`*

Comment: Thanks Scott, I thought only text things went inside quotation marks so didn't think of that!

Comment: You're welcome. It is a bit counterintuitive, excelwise.